# How to use this and super in polymorphism in js ES6

Tags: javascript, polymorphism, this, super, es6-class

I want to have 3 classes which are related. A *Node* class a *DoorNode* class and a *SisterDoorNode* class.

There are different types of nodes, which all have an id, a position, connections and a few functions.

One of these types are door nodes, which, just like the sister door nodes, have the node type "door", a corresponding element and a few functions. Their id and position are calculated in one way.

Then there are also sister door nodes. They have a different way of calculating the id and the position and also have a boolean that states that they are a sister door node.

This is how I wanted it to look like:

```
class Node {
    constructor(id, pos) {
        this.id = id;
        this.pos = pos;
        this.connections = [];
    }

    addConnection(c) {
        //A few functions all nodes need
    }
}

class DoorNode extends Node {
    constructor(door) {
        //Both of these are needed for all Nodes but are calculated in a different way for DoorNode and SisterDoorNode
        let id = this.getId(door);
        let pos = this.getPos(door);
        super(id, pos);

        //Both of these are needed in SisterDoorNode and DoorNode
        this.nodeType = "door";
        this.correspondingElement = door;
    }

    getId(door) {
        return door.id;
    }

    getPos(door) {
        return door.pos;
    }

    getDoorSize() {
        //Some calculations I need for both DoorNode + SisterDoorNode
    }
}

class SisterDoorNode extends DoorNode {
    constructor(door) {
        super(door);
        this.isSisterNode = true;
    }

    getId(door) {
        return door.id + ".2";
    }

    getPos(door) {
        return new Point(door.pos.x + 10, door.pos.y + 10);
    }
}
```

but since I can't use a *this* before a *super()* this does not work. What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide implementations of `getId` and `getPos` for both `DoorNode` and `SisterDoorNode`? That would help narrow down what the best option is.

Comment: Here you go.That is just about how they are implemented. Anything else would go to deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're dead on about not being able to use 'this' before 'super', as there is no 'this' to reference before the base class' constructor has finished running.

There are a few solutions to this, but they involve restructuring your code.

1) pass in the `id` and `pos` as params, just like the base class is doing.

2) Make `getId` and `getPos` static methods. ( this will introduce new complexities to do with using static variables )

3) make `pos` and `id` optional, and set them sometime after the super call.

4) you could just reference the props directly; `super( door.id, door.pos )`, but that won't work in your extended class that is doing logic on the `id` and `pos`

Update to include example of using a static function with a super call.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(door) {
        super( Foo.GetNodeFromDoor( door ) );
        // can now use `this`
    }
    
    
    static GetNodeFromDoor( door ) {
      // `this` refers to the static namespace, and not to the instance of the class. 
      return {
        id: door.id + ".2",
        pos: new Point(
          door.pos.x + 10,
          door.pos.y + 10
        )
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: 3) is not possible because they are not optional.
2) seems to me as a weird way to go arround the problem in a simple way but it does not make sense to me.
1) might be possible but then the calculations would have to be in a different location where they dont belong... I'm not so sure which one to use

Comment: you're changing the interface of the class, extending in this way doesn't actually make logical sense in general from a code design point of view. It's much better practice to try and retain the same interface when extending.

Comment: I was about to recommend static methods too @IceRevenge. I think it makes sense because in the constructor you don't really have instance yet, so calling instance methods is a little smelly.

Comment: With interface you mean the input parameters? Is it actually better to put the calculations then somewhere where they dont belong? Or do the calculations not belong there?

Comment: @MarkMeyer So you mean it's bad to use this. call any function in the constructor? Should you put all of that into a seperate e.g. setup() function?

Comment: @IceRevenge Yes, sorry, I do mean the input parameters here, but this thinking applies to the entire interface of the class as a whole. I like to externalize calculations in one-off static functions in a helper or utility class.

Comment: @StevenStark could you write a specific code example in a seperate answer or edit this answer?

Comment: @IceRevenge This involves you changing your code design.

Comment: @StevenStark I don't quite understand how the Helper class would looke like. That's why I asked for an example. Would the calculations be called inside of the constructor then? Do you need 2 different helper classes per node type? They are probably all static functions right? How would you call that class?

Comment: @IceRevenge I have updated the answer to include an example for you, I hope it fits your needs and helps you. Remember that static functions do not share the scope as with your class, they share a new scope among other statics.